# How does the following script works when started with a NPM build command

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, tsc

I have package.JSON file in which the script is mentioned as,

```
 "scripts": {
    "typings": "typings install",
    "build": "tsc && webpack",
    "watch": "npm-run-all -p -r -l tsc-watch webpack-watch",
    "tsc-watch": "tsc -w",
    "webpack-watch": "webpack -w",
    "clean": "rm -rf built",
    "minify": "webpack --optimize-minimize --optimize-dedupe",
    "start": "http-server -p 8000",
    "pretest": "tsc -p tests",
    "test": "mocha test/tests",
    "foo": "mocha test/tests"
  },
```

When npm is used as build with command, "run start build", In which order is script executed

Answer (score 1):

Running `npm run start build` is going to run the `"start": "http-server -p 8000",` first and then `"build": "tsc && webpack",`. Although here since the *start* command is an http-server and will never return until cancelled, it should never get to call the next command.

The NPM `run` command also called `run-script` allows to run arbitrary commands defined in the package.json file.

ref: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts , https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script